# How to view the slices of a 3d stl file separately in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, graphics, 3d, stl-format

I am trying to load a stl file and trying to view the slices of the stl file.
I have tried this:

```
import numpy as np
from stl import mesh
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

## Load the STL file

```
mesh_data = mesh.Mesh.from_file('MyStl.stl')
```

## Define the slicing axis (X, Y, or Z)

```
slicing_axis = 'Y'  # Replace with the desired axis
```

## Define the number of slices

```
num_slices = 10  # Adjust the number of slices as needed
```

## Calculate the range along the slicing axis

```
axis_range = mesh_data.points[:, 2]  # Assuming Z-axis slicing
```

## Create evenly spaced slice positions

```
slice_positions = np.linspace(min(axis_range), max(axis_range), num_slices)
```

## Iterate through the slices and create 2D images

```
for i, slice_position in enumerate(slice_positions):
# Define a small tolerance for matching vertices
    tolerance = 1e-6

# Create a mask to extract the slice
    if slicing_axis == 'X':
       mask = np.isclose(mesh_data.points[:, 0], slice_position, atol=tolerance)
    elif slicing_axis == 'Y':
       mask = np.isclose(mesh_data.points[:, 1], slice_position, atol=tolerance)
    elif slicing_axis == 'Z':
       mask = np.isclose(mesh_data.points[:, 2], slice_position, atol=tolerance)

# Extract the vertices for the slice
    sliced_vertices = mesh_data.points[mask]

# Create a 2D plot of the slice (you can use any 2D plotting library)
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(sliced_vertices[:, 0], sliced_vertices[:, 1], s=1)
    plt.axis('equal')  # Ensure equal aspect ratio for the plot
    plt.title(f'Slice {i+1}')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.show()
```

I am getting the plots but not able to view any thing in the plots meaning I'm just getting empty plots.Help me in viewing the slices .Thanks in advance.

Comment: STL does not have any slices you have to cut the mesh yourself. Some 3D rendering engines and APIs can be configured to do this for example in OpenGL you can simply discard any fragment outside the region of slice with simple if condition in fragment shader ... without the need for any geometric cutting by planes ... You want axis aligned slices so you can even configure camera so it shows only the slice you want even without shaders

Comment: By discarding the fragments will i be able to get 2d slices of my stl file?or are you telling that we will acheive parts of 3d stl file we have?

Comment: if you do just zero thickness slice this way you will get the contour however most likely with holes (like doted lines) ... its better to have "finite thickness" slice instead so the lines will be fully filled ... so I would chose slice thickness to be around pixel size (or some small multiple of it) ....